# Uploaded image cannot be seen

Tags: image-upload

When I upload a picture in my back end I just get this:
[image]

I guess it happens after I installed a patch. As I try to click the "little broken picture" I get redirected to a site saying "403 forbidden".
Any ideas what to do.
Regards 
Jesper

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved. Had problems with permissions.
Edited the following: public_html/lib/Varien/File uploader.php

Line 219: changed from 0640 to 0666

Line 541: changed from 0750 to 0777